# SharePoint list attachments get and add

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, scope

JS novice here but I am trying to get my head around it slowly :)

Been struggling with this for a bit and hopefully someone can provide guidance.

What I am trying to do is get attachments from a list item in SharePoint using the pnp-js-core library.

Once I have the attachments data (names and blobs) I am going to add them to another list item.

I am following the examples provided here. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Attachments

While I am able to get most of the way I am stuck with scoping vars correctly or maybe the structure of the code itself.

Guidance much appreciated!

```
  var ItemID = GetUrlKeyValue("ID");

  var sourcelist = $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List A");

  var sourceitem = sourcelist.items.getById(ItemID);

  var destlist = $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List B");

  var fileInfos = [];

  var filename = "";

  // get current item attachments
  sourceitem.attachmentFiles.get().then(v => {

    for (var k in v) {

      console.log(k + " - " + v[k].FileName);

      filename = v[k].FileName;

      // get currect item attachments blobs
      sourceitem.attachmentFiles.getByName(filename).getBlob().then(b => {

        blob = b;

        console.log(b);

      });

      fileInfos.push({
        name: filename,
        content: blob
      });

    }
  // adds attachments
    destlist.items.getById(2).attachmentFiles.addMultiple(fileInfos).then(r => {

      console.log(r);
    });

  });

  console.log(fileInfos);
```

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: Yes! it give an errror "ReferenceError: blob is not defined"

Comment: add `var blob = null` after `filename = v[k].FileName;`

Comment: Thanks! but when I do that the "value" of content: blob when pushed to the fileInfos array is content:null.

Comment: ok, i need to debug this

Comment: @tinamou Thanks! Maybe I need to restructure my code so that the var data is accessible when needed? but any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Ok so I have been experimenting on this and apparently by adding  `k = 0;` before `for (var k in v) ` did the trick. Any ideas why ? :)

Comment: No idea :O. Sorry for not being any help.

Comment: @tinamou no problem :) thanks for looking into it. I'll leave it open for a bit, maybe someone else wants to chime in.